# Ubuntu 18 cannot connect to the Internet using eth network

Tags: networking, dhcp

I just installed Ubuntu in an old PC and I installed the Fog Server on it. For some reason, I made a mistake that I enabled the DHCP function, and I tried the way from other website to disable it. I did the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep dhcp    
sudo apt-get remove isc-dhcp-client   
sudo apt-get remove isc-dhcp-common   
sudo apt-get remove isc-dhcp-server
```

And when I run the commands

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep dhcp    
isc-dhcp-client     deinstall   
isc-dhcp-server     deinstall
```

And now I cannot connect to the Internet and even there is no connection icon in the menu of the upper right corner. I think remove that DHCP stuff caused this disconnection and wonder if there is any solutions to reinstall it.

The Ubuntu cannot connect to the Internet, but I got a Windows PC here to help.

Comment: If it's a fresh install, easiest and quickest is perhaps to reinstall, and not remove the dhcp-client the next time.

Answer (score 0):

> systemctl stop $(fogserver)

-- any and all things installed with this server

> ip addr flush eth0
>
> sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd

verify you picked up a IP assuming u had another dhcp server serving them

> ip a

but if its a new install yea probably make a base img for ubuntu and start over and if it happens again keep cloning using that base image/clone vm